# Snap SVG / jQuery Collision

Tags: jquery, svg, particles

I try to create a particle effect with snap SVG and i want my particles bounce off the edges of the SVG.

Here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmsr2rpw/)

```
        if (  pElement < 0 || pElement > eval(w)) {
            var vlcx = - vlcx;
            var vlcy = vlcy;
        };

        if (  pElement < 0 || pElement > eval(h)) {
            vlcx = vlcx;
            vlcy = - vlcy;
        }
```

I reverse velocity but .. nothing

Comment: What does "nothing" mean? Error messages? Your code has no effect? If it's the latter, are you sure it's even executing?

Comment: No error message. Particles leave the svg i think i've forgot one condition i don't know . It seems correct for me .

Comment: Update of the fiddle .. Now they bounce on the edges http://jsfiddle.net/dmsr2rpw/2/

Comment: Does that mean your question is answered? If so, you should post your solution as your own answer.

Comment: Not answered :( if you prefer,when the particle affects one side of the svg, it bounces and goes to the center of the area. it should not remain stuck to the wall.

Answer (score 0):

A few corrections in your fiddle. Firstly, you need to update the velocity each time you move the particle, else it wont reverse

```
    pElement.attr({
        cx: eval(pElementX+=vlcx),
        cy: eval(pElementY+=vlcy),
        vx: vlcx,
        vy: vlcy,
    });
```

Secondly in your code above, `pElement` should be either `pElementX` or `pElementY`. Use `posX` or `posY` so we dont get mixed up with `pElement`.

Thirdly, use `console.log(i,'/', posX,'/', posY,'/', vlcx,'/', vlcy)` to debug the position.

Potential bug: Use `posX < radiusP/2` instead of `posX < 0`, so particle doesn't fly out of SVG box before reversing. Similarly `posX > (width - radiusP/2)`

Note: If `Math.random() == 10` for both `X` and `Y` velocity, you'll have a stationary particle.